# PowerShell function not acting as planned

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, powershell-5.0

I am taking a stab at creating my first PowerShell function and it is annoying me. I am trying to offline and online cluster disk on a DR server that uses replicated disk from the production site. here is the function:

```
    function Update-Cluster {
    param (
        [string]$cluster,
        [string]$direction
    )
    $cluster
    $direction
<#
This section goes to the cluster and onlines the disk. They had been originally set up as resources so they show as off line.
#>
    if ($direction -like "*failover*") {
        Write-Host "Collecting disk information from host"
        $onDisk = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $cluster -ScriptBlock {Get-ClusterResource  | Where-Object {$_.name -like "*disk*" -and $_.OwnerGroup -like "Available Storage"}}
        Write-Host "Onlining Disk"
        foreach ($cdisk in $onDisk) {
            $onCommand = @{ 
                ComputerName = $cluster
                ScriptBlock = { Start-ClusterResource $args[0] }
                ArgumentList = $cdisk.name
            }
        Invoke-Command @onCommand 
        }
    }
    else {
<#
Here we offline the disk that have been removed as a SQL resource
#>
        Write-Host "Colecting disk information from host"
        $offDisk = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $cluster -ScriptBlock {Get-ClusterResource | Where-Object {$_.name -like "*disk*" -and $_.OwnerGroup -like "Available Storage"}}
        Write-Host "Offlining disk"
        foreach ($cdisk in $offdisk) {
            $offCommand = @{ 
                ComputerName = $cluster
                ScriptBlock = { Stop-ClusterResource $args[0] }
                ArgumentList = $cdisk.name
            }
            Invoke-Command @offCommand 
        }
    }
}
```

The first issue I have is it fails the if statement. I call this function with "Update-Cluster(na2-pdsqldb13,$stage) the value of $stage in the first pass is "failover". I validate the parameters are being passed correctly with a repeat of the function parameters ($cluster and $direction) in the script. however apparently failover is not like failover. The second issue is it fails on the first Invoke-Command because for some reason the value of $cluster is substituted with the value of $direction:

```
[failover] Connecting to remote server failover failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error occurred while using Kerberos authentication: 
Cannot find the computer failover. Verify that the computer exists on the network and that the name provided is spelled correctly. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting 
Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (failover:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NetworkPathNotFound,PSSessionStateBroken
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I "fixed" it by changing the function call from a positional call `Update-Cluster("na2-pdsqldb13,$stage)` to a named call `Update-Cluster -cluster "na2-pdsqldb13" -direction $stage`. Do not know why this worked and the other did not.

Comment: You were indeed calling the function incorrectly.  It's a common mistake when coming from other languages, where function and/or method calls are something like `Function( Arg1, Arg2)`.  PowerShell will treat the `()` as precedence operators and run/evaluate the enclosed statements/expressions, then pass the result as a single argument.  In this case that would have been a single 2 element array.

Comment: Correct invocation with positional parameter binding would look like: `Update-Cluster na2-pdsqldb13 $stage`